# Complaint against final variable

Tags: java, final

Okay, so as far as I know, I understand these things about a `final` variable.

1. It should be assigned only once
2. All the `final` variables should be initialized before the constructor completes

Now using the above, I do not understand how the below doesn't work:

```
public class FinalTest implements AnotherClass {

    private final Something something;
    private final otherthing;

    @Override
    public void setStuff(Something something) {
        this.something = something;
        this.otherthing = new SomeClass(something);
    }

    public FinalTest(Something something) {
        setStuff(something);
    }
}
```

Here, before the constructor completes the `final` variables are being set. So why does the compiler complain against it?

Comment: What is the type of `otherthing`?

Comment: Here's the JLS chapter on definite assignment for you. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html Enjoy.

Comment: Final variables are nice but there are a lot of times they just don't make sense.  If you don't have any way to set it from within your class it is still "Logically" final, so don't get too hung up on forcing it.  Also consider the validity of calling a method (which assumes your class is in a finished state) from a constructor (responsible for finishing the classes state).  This needs to be done with care.

Comment: @BillK: Thanks, that actually made sense. Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not necessary that your method gets called only from constructor, it can be called from outside your constructor also. And even a second call might be added to the same constructor in future also.

Even though you might not have used it now, but Compiler cannot be sure about it, so it does not allow it. In technical term, there is no `definite assignment`.

**For e.g: -** suppose you instantiate your class from `main`: -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FinalTest obj = new FinalTest(something);

    obj.setStuff(something); // There you go. This cannot be prevented. 
}
```

See [JLS - Definite Assignments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html) for detailed explanation on this.

Comment: This explanation does not makes sense since if I make it private then it should allow me to do it by this explanation. The real reason is there is no definite assignment.

Comment: @AmitD.. Yeah you are quite right. Should have added that term.

Answer (score 8):

Because nobody is stopping you from calling `setStuff()` a second time later on in the life of the object, which would be illegal.

`final` fields can only be assigned in code blocks that are guaranteed to run only once, that is constructors and instance initialisers. (Or a static initialiser in case of a `static final` field.)

More on this can be found in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html).

Comment: also worth mentioning that it is possible to observe a final variable in two different states (null and assigned value) if the final is accessed by an overridable method in the constructor (which is why constructors should never invoke overridable methods)

Answer (score 3):

because the compiler doesn't know that the only call to

```
public void setStuff(Something something) {
    this.something = something;
    this.otherthing = new SomeClass(something);
}
```

is from the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Should the following line be

```
private final otherthing;
```

something like

```
private final Something otherthing;
```

you are missing the class.

Comment: does not address the question

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note:

```
@Override
public void setStuff(Something something) {
    this.something = something;
    this.otherthing = new SomeClass(something);
}

public FinalTest(Something something) {
    setStuff(something);
}
```

That's really a bad design. You should not invoke an overridable method from the constructor.

Comment: I know it's not realted to the concrete problem. But I think it's a good advice. Why downvote?

Comment: because it's not related to the concrete problem

Comment: I think it was downvoted because it's not really an answer, should be a a comment instead. It is a very useful thing to know though and can't be repeated enough times.

Comment: `setStuff` is not just overridable, it's overridden.